# BroadcastReceiver doesn't work properly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, keyevent

I'm trying to write app using Broadcastreceiver. Unfortunately, it does not work properly (it does nothing). Could someone help me?
Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyApp extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        registerReceiver(keyboardReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT));
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver keyboardReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent i) {
            KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent)i.getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            int test = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(test), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: what are you expecting from your broadcast receiver? what event are you listening for

Answer (score 0):

You should use an action, not an extra, when registering your `BroadcastReceiver`:

```
registerReceiver(keyboardReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT));
```

Try to use something like that:

```
registerReceiver(keyboardReceiver, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON));
```